# How to add Paragraph fields to Block in Drupal 8?

Tags: drupal, drupal-8, paragraph

I'd like to be able to add multiple Paragraph components to a Block in Drupal 8.

A Paragraph type will be created with fields in it, and the ideal use case for the user is to add a new paragraph field that works like Entity Reference's.

Just wondering if there is an out-of-the-box solution for this, or am I looking at a custom implementation?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do this by:

1: Click Structure
2: Click Block Layout
3: Click Custom Block Library
4: Click Block Types Tab
5: Click Add Custom Block

From here it is the same as creating a standard content type. You then apply the block type you just created to a new custom block.

Hope this helps. Images are for Ref.
[Stage 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WzTOo.jpg)

[Stage 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3nIOc.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

- Create Custom Block type from "admin/structure/block/block-content/types/add"
- In "Mange fields" select "paragraph" from the "Reference Revision"
  [image: Please see the screen shot]
- Now Select the paragraph that you created as shown below.
  [image: Please see the screen shot]

Answer (score -1):

paragraph block is also an option . https://www.drupal.org/project/paragraph_blocks

Comment: Welcome to SO! Don't post links to websites, as it might be broken or taken down in future. Instead, explain the solution.

Comment: Sorry you got downvoted. I have a feeling this wouldn't have been downvoted if the question had been posed on https://drupal.stackexchange.com because providing links to Drupal modules is considered a valid and helpful solution.  "it might be broken or taken down" is inaccurate for Drupal modules, because contrib modules are not taken down lightly, and all community members know very well to use contrib modules at their own risk.  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯